# How can we manage same database for flutter app and a website made form Tailwind CSS, HTML and JS in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I'm making an flutter app and a website for my collage project but having difficulty to manage the same database for both in PHP, MySQL.

The flutter app and the website are on different devices.

If anyone have the solution for this or have knowledge about this, then please help With sample code or explanation you can give.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, you want same database for both `flutter` project and `website`, You must be looking for fetching the data from the MySql using `REST API`.

You can create endpoint api's using php with the mysql database, and use the same api endpoint from both the

1. website using [axios](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-axios-with-react/)
2. flutter using [http package](https://www.bing.com/search?q=flutter+http&cvid=b7be82519150409d834fdeec8092f40b&aqs=edge..69i57l2j69i59j69i65j69i60l3.1800j0j1&pglt=675&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=DCTS)

Comment: Is it still works if the app  and website are on separate devices ?